# Why aren't Steel Prefab Buildings common for residential use?

Tags: steel, building-design

Steel prefabricated buildings cost less, require less time and provide a reasonable quality compared to concrete buildings.

They are common for warehouses, offices and other types of buildings. Also, there are prefabricated steel houses for residential use.

However, I have noticed that steel buildings/apartments are rare/non-existent. Is there a reason for this.

I am specifically asking regarding the usage of prefabricated steel in apartment and/or multistory buildings for regular use.

Comment: I'm not a structural engineer; but I assume it has to do with the strength of it.  A pre-fabbed steel structure is probably only able to self-support for a few stories.

Comment: water / moisture turns steel to rust eventually so the life may not be too good - what are some of the oldest buildings made of? And what buildings will be around in 300 years - our concrete ones or some of those designed and build in the 17th and 18th C ??

Comment: Err, what's a steel prefabricated building?

Comment: By pre-fabrication building, I suppose he/she means Pre-Engineered Buildings (PEB). Am I right?

Comment: No actually, I mean prefabricated buildings made of steel

Comment: I would guess that it has to do with uniformity of structure. e.g. Every warehouse is basically the same shape, a big cube. Residential (houses and apartments) tend to want to be different and unique, or they need to fit a certain site shape.

Comment: This question needs to be further specified, most importantly with a region or market of interest. Different materials and methods dominate in different regions and markets for a wide variety of reasons. What constitutes "common?" What constitutes "regular use?" What sort of an answer are you looking for—are you working on an engineering project, doing research for a course in urban planning, looking at designs to build a home, etc.? As it is currently written this question looks like a fine conversation starter but this is not a discussion forum, we are looking for expert Q&A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually quite common in Scandinavia in my experience, using steel beams and columns with concrete hollowcore slabs. [This PDF](http://www.stalforbund.no/uploads/source/files/Materialet/Hulldekker/Veileder_Hulldekker_2008_2.pdf) describes one example of such a system.

Comment: Please provide a source/examples - downvoted as this doesn't currently answer the question

Comment: Check this out, it describes the system. It's common in Scandinavia, and I am in the business.

http://www.stalforbund.no/uploads/source/files/Materialet/Hulldekker/Veileder_Hulldekker_2008_2.pdf

Comment: @JonathanRSwift You're not doing the site any favors by downvoting reasonable, expert answers to bad questions without addressing the question itself.

Comment: @Air I’ve removed said downvote following an edit to the answer. I’d say providing a vague and hand-waving answer to a bad question, without addressing the question, is also not best practice!

Comment: @JonathanRSwift Yep, but Joel is new to the site, whereas you and I are not. ;)

Comment: Thanks :) My point is i work in the industry and we deliver just as many residential projects as we do offices. If the original poster is thinking about pure steel buildings it is not very common, because concrete slabs are required to satisfy demands of sound proofing and fire resistance. Massive wood slabs are on the rise, but it is not as common as concrete hollowcore.